# SMLNJ REPL error "!* unable to process ..."

Tags: smlnj

I am using SML NJ v110.78 on Mac OS X 10.9.  I am trying to use command-line arguments from BASH, like so:

```
sml progname.sml 2.0 1.0.
```

The program progname.sml compiles and runs and uses the command-line arguments to produce a value (using SMLofNJ.getArgs() function), but at the end of the processing, the REPL returns the error:

```
!* unable to process `2.0' (unknown extension `0')
!* unable to process `1.0' (unknown extension `0')
-
```

How do I avoid those final error messages?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to terminate the REPL with an exit statement:

```
val _ = OS.Process.exit(OS.Process.success);
```

When you don't exit the REPL in above manner then the command-line arguments are regarded by the interpreter as compiler extensions, hence the feedback:

```
!* unable to process `2.0' (unknown extension `0')
```

BTW: You can use `OS.Process.exit(OS.Process.success);` to exit the REPL as a cleaner alternative to CTRL+Z

[How do I quit SML?](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/FAQ/usage.html)

[ML Command Line Options Cheat Sheet](http://cs.williams.edu/~freund/cs334/auxread/ML-commandline.html)